# How to pass more than one parameter using display tag?

Tags: struts, query-string, jsp-tags, displaytag, querystringparameter

I'm using display tag. but i want to pass more than one parameter in  the runtime. How can i pass the more than one parameter in the display:column using the 'paramProperty' and 'paramid'

My code is ,

```
<display:table name="${weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportForm.asnAccuracyListQO}" uid="asnAccuracyListUID" sort="list" defaultsort="1" 
                                        requestURI="/weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportPre.do?method=httpGet" excludedParams="method"
                                        decorator="com.ford.mpl.superg.decorator.WeeklyDeliveryInstancesTypeTableDecorator" keepStatus="true">
    <%@include file="/jsp/include/displaytag.jsp"%>
    <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.firstWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyFirstWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.secondWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracySecondWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.thirdWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyThirdWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.fourthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyFourthWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.fifthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyFifthWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.sixthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracySixthWeekOfCount"/>

    <c:if test="${(asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType != null && asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType != 'Sum')}">
        <display:column property="instanceTypeDescription" title="Instance Type" sortable="false"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${(asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType != null && asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType == 'Sum')}">
        <display:column property="instanceType" title="Instance Type" sortable="false" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center"/>
    </c:if>
    <display:column property="firstWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFirstWeekOfCount}" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportPost.do?method=WeeklyDlvyInstExcelReport" paramProperty="instanceType,ratingElementId" paramId="instanceTypeForJSP,ratingElementIdForJSP" sortable="false" />
    <display:column property="secondWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracySecondWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  />
    <display:column property="thirdWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyThirdWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  />
    <display:column property="fourthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFourthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" />
    <display:column property="fifthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFifthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" />
    <display:column property="sixthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracySixthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"/>
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply generate the link yourself:

```
<display:column>
    <c:url value="..." var="theUrl">
        <c:param name="..." value="..."/>
        <c:param name="..." value="..."/>
    </c:url>
    <a href="<c:out value="${theUrl"}/>">...</a>
</display:column>
```

Comment: ..i got the answer  <display:column property="firstWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFirstWeekOfCount}" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportPost.do?method=WeeklyDlvyInstExcelReport&ratingElementId=${asnAccuracyListUID.ratingElementId}&instanceTypeForJSP=${asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType}" sortable="false"/>

Answer (score 2):

Dont use this because it gives first row only as parameters

```
 <display:table  cellpadding="2" name="dl" id="data" pagesize="500" requestURI="dataDisplayFormOne.htm" class="main_grid_table">
    <display:column property="facid" title="facid"  href="printUserForm20.htm?factid=${data.facid}&Licensenumber=${data.LICENSE_NO_FORM20}"  class="main_grid_column"/>
 </display:table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<display:column property="firstWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFirstWeekOfCount}" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportPost.do?method=WeeklyDlvyInstExcelReport&ratingElementIdFromJSP=${asnAccuracyListUID.ratingElementId}" paramProperty="instanceType" paramId="instanceTypeFromJSP" sortable="false"/>
```